# while (cin>> struct str) in c++ how can I use?

Tags: c++

I'm having a trouble when I use while(cin) with struct. Would someone please make me clear about this problem? I don't know whether this kind of post was asked or not. If it was please forgive me and my bad english as well.

```
struct ThiSinh{
     string m_HT;
     float m_H;
};
```

I overload operator >> for it

```
bool operator >> (istream& is, ThiSinh &ts){
    getline(is, ts.m_HT);
    is >> ts.m_H;
    is.ignore();
    return ???;
}
```

Because while (cin >> ThiSinh) require a bool type, so I dont know what number or data it should return. And how to break the while loop when I press ctrl + Z.
  I have also tried

```
while(cin){
   ThiSinh ts;
   cin >> ts;
}
```

and it worked but I dont want to get that false data. So someone please helps me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an overload which converts an `std::istream` to `bool`.

Comment: [The mighty operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). Write `ThiSinh ts; while(cin >> ts){ // use ts }`

Comment: ok now I get it, thank both of you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator >>` returns a `bool`, which is extremely unusual for a stream extraction operator, and renders it unusuable in most streaming contexts. Such operators are expected to return a reference to the stream on which they operate:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& is, ThiSinh &ts){
    getline(is, ts.m_HT);
    is >> ts.m_H;
    is.ignore();
    return is;
}
```

This is how multiple exrtactions actually work:

```
std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

Effectively, this first does `auto &tmp = operator>>(std::cin, a)`, and then calls `operator>>(tmp, b)`, and so on.

The reason why streams (and by extension, stream extraction operations) can be used in conditionals is that `std::istream` (and `std::ostream`) defines a conversion to `bool` (which returns `true` iff the stream is in error-free state); that conversion is then invoked by the conditional.

In other words, this:

```
while (std::cin >> ts)
```

effectively becomes this:

```
while (static_cast<bool>(operator>>(std::cin, ts)))
```

and the cast is possible because `operator>>` returns `std::istream&` and `std::istream` defines a conversion to `bool`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your answer but I cant find a solution from this, arent I? or i have problem about reading in English idk ):

Comment: @ThuậnThiên Change the operator's return type and return the stream you've just read from. The first code exceprt in my answer shows that. The rest of the answer is just explanation *why* do it that way.

Comment: @ThuậnThiên I've added a bit more explanation to the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: It helps me a lot. Thanks very much @Angew.